# Get Element with Hyphen in Javascript

Tags: javascript

HTML snippet:

```
<input title="List" data-id="1698481">
```

In IE 11 console, I've been trying various commands, and everything without a hyphen comes back correctly until I hit "data-id."

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].title
"List"
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].data-id
'id' is undefined
```

As per other threads on this subject, I tried other syntaxes (camel case, etc.), but I still can't get it to return any value

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].dataId
undefined
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].["data-id"]
Expected identifier
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].['data-id']
Expected identifier
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: [Access 'data-' attribute without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912246/access-data-attribute-without-jquery) and [How to get the data-id attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

Comment: I recommend to revisit some JavaScript basics about accessing properties:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json. (`[0].['data-id']` is simply invalid syntax)

Answer (score 4):

Use `.getAttribute()`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("data-id")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `data-*` attributes are special:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].dataset.id
```

data-* attributes are converted from hyphens to camelCasing, so a `data-test-attribute="test"` would be equivalent to:

```
htmlElement.dataset.testAttribute; // test
```

For more information, see [the MDN on dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: That works too, but it's not that widely supported as `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: @Gothdo You are correct, but the support is pretty wide: http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why ["data-id"] would be undefined in console.log, unlinke ["title"] / .title.