# How to access data attributes from event object

Tags: reactjs

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/69z2wepo/46260/)

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  handleClick(event){
    console.log('target info', event.currentTarget);
    console.log('event info', event);
    var sortOrder = event.currentTarget.sortorder;

    console.log('sortOrder: ', sortOrder);
    alert(sortOrder);//Should say "asc"
  },
  render: function() {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: "red", fontSize: '5em'}} data-sortorder="asc" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here Please</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Expected Output:  **asc** 
Actual:      **undefined**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access 'data-' attribute without jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912246/access-data-attribute-without-jquery)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything specifically to do with React, rather with the lack of understanding how `data-` attributes work.

Comment: @FelixKling - `event` is a [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#syntheticevent) right?  Don't you need to understand how to navigate `SyntheticEvent`?

Comment: Well, it has the same API as the normal event object and `event.currentTarget` is a plain old DOM element.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I updated your fiddle:

I was able to do it just by referencing with "getAttribute"

```
 event.target.getAttribute("data-sortorder");
```

this is with refs
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/46265/

```
 var sortOrder = this.refs.tester.getAttribute("data-sortorder");
 alert(sortOrder);//Should say "asc"
},
  render: function() {
    return <div style={{backgroundColor: "red", fontSize: '5em'}} data-sortorder="asc" ref="tester" onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Here Please</div>;
  }
});
```

Do this:-

1. change your element, by adding a "ref" attribute.

   ```
   div style={{backgroundColor: "red", fontSize: '5em'}} data-sortorder="asc" ref="tester" onClick={this.handleClick}
   ```
2. Then get that attribute like so: `this.refs.tester.getAttribute("data-sortorder")`

OR PER ORIGINAL REQUEST, w/o REFS:

3. Or per "event specific" -- it worked properly referencing it like so:
   `event.target.getAttribute("data-sortorder");`

---

**NOTE**: Now that we are 6yrs later, you can also use: (per niko9911 suggestion below)

```
event.target.dataset.sortorder
```

--> You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can read out via a dataset property.

To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

Comment: `event.target.getAttribute("data-sortorder");` is what I wanted.  Glad we were able to do this without refs :).  I'll make it when the timer runs down.

Comment: Why is a ref better than using the `event` object?

Comment: Instead of using `event.target.getAttribute("data-sortorder");` you should utilize dataset. `event.target.dataset.sortorder`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 5):

Like @Niko9911 already mentioned in a comment, you can access all data attributes from the `element.dataset` property.

> You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can read out via a dataset property. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

You can read the data, and you can also set the attribute to something new.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.something');
element.addEventListener('click', handeClick);

function handeClick(e) {
  // READ
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.test);

  //WRITE
  e.currentTarget.dataset.test = 'bar';
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.test);
}
```

```html
<a class="something" data-test="foo">Click me.</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

All custom HTML atributes can be accessed through event itself:

```
event.target.attributes.MYATRIBUTE.value
```