# How to get specific data from $(this) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, this

When I do `console.log($(this));` I got the following information:-

[image: Image Here]

I want to join the `$(this)`, go into `context`, and then into `attributes`. How?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the data form attributes

Comment: _"data form attributes"_? Can you provide an example of an element, and then what information you want from it?

Comment: `this.getAttribute("ATTRIBUTE NAME")` is indescribably faster than jQuery. For certain attributes such as `id` or `href` you can even do `this.href`.

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] then edit question with a properly detailed problem description

Comment: you can use `$(this).attr('class'); $(this).attr('href');` to get the values of corresponding properties. And yes you can use jQuery without any issue for simple taks also.

Comment: Instead of `$(this).attr('class'); $(this).attr('href');`, use `this.className; this.href`. It's faster and more readable.

Comment: var a=$(this); a.context.attributes; very simple

Comment: @NegiRox: Then just use `this.attributes`. Why wrap `this` in jQuery, if you're just using `context` to get back to `this`?

Comment: yes you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you want to get the attribute from this element-

```
<div class="test_class" data-somevalue="this is value"> </div>
```

You can use-

```
$(".test_class").attr("data-somevalue")
//or
$(".test_class").data("somevalue")
```

In your case, you can also use

```
const finalVal = Object.assign({}, $(this), $(this).context, $(this). attributes)
```

Comment: glad to see that finally jQuery code answer is selected

Comment: @AlivetoDie: Funny enough, for data attributes there's not a simple native JS answer. This is one of those cases where jQuery is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Cerbrus  this isn't funny enough:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15912286

Comment: @AlivetoDie: Except that jQuery has some automatic data type conversion, which is a good reason to use jQuery here.