# select nested data-click within data-template

Tags: javascript, jquery

My template involving parent `div` with attribute of `data-template` and child `button` with attribute of `data-click`:

```
<script type="text/html" id="containerTemplate">
    <div data-template="myTemplate">    
        <ul>      
          <li>
            <button type="button" data-click="done">
              <span>some text</span>
            </button>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</script>
```

How can i select the `button` with the `data-click="done"`?

I've tried this

```
const doneBtn = document.querySelector('[data-template = myTemplate] [data-click = done]');
if (doneBtn) {
    //register some event listeners
}
```

But the `doneBtn` is returning null.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can use `.data()` (Source: https://api.jquery.com/data/) or you can use `$(selector).attr("data-click") === "done"`

Comment: If you are interested in doing it without jquery, follow this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912246/access-data-attribute-without-jquery

Comment: are you familiar with templates? you have to actually inject that script template in the DOM to be able to target it with querySelector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put your html code in javascript tags that's why javascript was unable to access your html DOM. Try below code it will work.

```
<div data-template="myTemplate">    
    <ul>      
      <li>
        <button type="button" data-click="done">
          <span>some text</span>
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div> 


<script type="text/javascript">
 const doneBtn = document.querySelector('[data-template = myTemplate] [data-click = done]');
if (doneBtn) {
    //register some event listeners
    console.log($(doneBtn).html());
}
  </script>
```